# Implementing Granular Access Control in SharePoint Lists for Multi-Departmental Use

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm currently enhancing a SharePoint list for collaborative use among various department managers, which includes sensitive staff details. I aim to establish a robust security model aligning with these criteria:

**1.** Departmental Privacy: Each manager requires access exclusively to their department's list, without visibility or editing rights to other departments' lists.

**2.** Staff Restrictions: Staff members (excluding managers) should neither view nor edit any segment of the list.
Upper Management Oversight: A senior manager needs comprehensive access to all departmental data. The necessity for editing privileges is under consideration.

**3.** My query is about the feasibility of configuring such a nuanced permission structure within SharePoint lists. If you have navigated similar scenarios or have insights into structuring permissions effectively while ensuring stringent access control in SharePoint, your guidance would be immensely valuable.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I read about your needs. I don't think independent access between departments can be achieved in a SharePoint list.

You can build a list for each department. For each department manager give them access to their department list.

For each department employee give them read permission level to their department list.

For senior managers give them edit permission level or higher for each department list.